# How can i install php5-dev in Centos 6

Tags: mongodb, centos, centos6

I am using centos 6. i want to install php5-dev on my cloud server. Because in my server I got phpize error.

This is not working on my server. My PHP version is 5.3.3. I need to `pecl install mongo`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

as root, execute the following command

```
yum install php-devel
```

Comment: im getting `Error: php56-cli conflicts with php-cli-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
`

Comment: @weber - you may need to uninstall php 5.3 to get version 5.6 installed.  Or have you worked this out already?

Comment: phpinfo shows im running php5.6, but are you saying that 5.3 is installed as well?

Comment: try 'php -v' to determine what is installed.  If you're on an Amazon instance or something, you may need to ask them.